# Download Exported excel file in the background with Action Cable

Tags: excel, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job, actioncable

I need a way where I can send a request to server and get immediate response but I need to create long excel file in background when the background job is finished the created file should be downloaded automatically. I have follow [this](http://jameshuynh.com/rails/action%20cable/file-saver/2017/10/27/download-exported-csv-in-the-background-with-action-cable-and-file-saver-js/) but here the file is being generated at client side I want to create the file on server side and can send via action cable the rest of things are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by sending a new request after creating file to download where I send file in response and after that I remove file from system